# Example of how to add secondary index when storing object in Riak with Java Client?

Tags: riak

I am storing a hash-map in a riak bucket like this:

```
bucket.store(key, docHashMap).execute();
```

I would like to store the object with a secondary index.

How would I accomplish this? I am aware that the `IRiakObject` has a `addIndex` method, but how do I access the `IRiakObject` before it is stored?

I would think that what I am trying to do is the expected use-case, yet I am not able to find any documentation or examples on this. If you can point me to one that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

**Update:**

@Brian Roach answered this on the Riak mailing list and below. Here is the custom class that I wrote that extends the HashMap:

```
class DocMap extends HashMap<String, Object> {
    /**
     * Generated id
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5807773481499313384L;

    @RiakIndex(name="status") private String status;

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

I can still use the object as an ordinary hashmap and store keys and values, but it will also write "status" to a secondary index (and actually end up being called "status_bin" since it's a string.

Comment: Caught this on the mailing list before here, but figured I'd copy the answer for reference on SO.

Comment: I imagine many people would benefit if the example of using a class that extends HashMap were to be part of the documentation. By doing it this way, it shows that you can have the same level of versatility in the Java client as you have with the python client (i.e. that you can store dict-like objects - HashMaps - that can have arbitrary field names, and still specify fields for a secondary index and similar things)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just passing in an instance of the core Java HashMap ... you can't.

The way the default `JSONConverter` works for metadata (such as indexes)
is via annotations.

The object being passed in needs to have a field annotated with
`@RiakIndex("index_name")`. That field can be a `Long`/`Set<Long>` or
`String`/`Set<String>` (for `_int` and `_bin` indexes respectively).

These are not converted to JSON so they won't affect your serialized
data. You can have multiple fields for multiple indexes.

You don't have to append "_int" or "_bin" to the index name in the
annotation - it's done automatically based on the type.

Easiest thing to do woud be to extend HashMap and simply add the
annotated field(s).